# specifying number of pages to print in C#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, printing

how can I specify printer and the number of pages to print,here is my code which prints all pages in pdf file,also it always uses default printer.

```
private void printPDFFile(string fileName)
    {
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();

        if (DialogResult.OK == pd.ShowDialog(this))
        {
          Process proc = new Process();
          pd.PrinterSettings.FromPage = 1;
          pd.PrinterSettings.ToPage = 2; 
          pd.PrinterSettings.PrintRange = PrintRange.SomePages;
          proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; //Hide the window.
          proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Foxit Software\Foxit                Reader\Foxit Reader.exe";

          proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-p \""+ fileName+ "\" \""       +pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName+"\"";

            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;//!! Don't create a Window.
            proc.Start();
            proc.CloseMainWindow();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The printing is not done in C#, but from Foxit Reader.

Look at [its manual (pdf)](http://foxit.vo.llnwd.net/o28/pub/foxit/manual/enu/FoxitReader30_Manual.pdf#page=144) for the options that control what you need. Use `-t <Printer>` to print to a specific printer.  It seems you can't print a specific page though, try to combine `-t` with `-n`.